Why does querying with multiple threads take almost as long as a single thread? Could the DB2 cursor be limiting me?
Service Method:
You have implemented a service method named selectUserService that takes two parameters, start and number, and returns a Cursor object.
Mapper Method: The selectUserService method internally calls a selectUserMapper method from a Mapper interface, which is responsible for the actual database query.
SQL Query: The corresponding SQL query is select * from user limit start,number, which is used to retrieve a range of data from the user table.
Composite Primary Key: The primary key of the user table is a composite key.
ResultSet Configuration: When executing the query, you have set fetchSize=2000 and resultSetType=FORWARD_ONLY, which are typically used to optimize performance and memory usage.
@Transactional Annotation: To prevent the Cursor from closing prematurely, you have applied the @Transactional annotation to a higher-level load method to ensure transaction integrity.
Multi-threaded Execution: In the load method, you have adopted a multi-threaded approach to call selectUserService, with each thread being assigned different start and number values, with the aim of reducing data loading time through parallel processing.
Thread Execution Issue: Despite initiating five threads, you observed that only one thread was executing, and other threads seemed to be waiting.
Thread Stack Snapshot: In the printed thread stack snapshot, you noticed the -locked keyword, indicating that threads might be waiting for a resource or lock.
Performance Issue: You found that the performance in a multi-threaded environment did not significantly improve and was similar to that of single-threaded execution.
This is a simple program with Spring Boot, MyBatis, and DB2, and I swear there are no other complex operations involved.
I tried to solve this problem from the following aspects: 1. My declarative transaction caused thread blocking, but I found that these threads did not use the same session or link after starting. 2. In addition, I thought that things caused It's locked, but it's obviously not because this is just a query. 3. So I speculate that the problem lies with the database.
